# Last/Newest mail of a thread - Gmail script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I have a problem with a script I wrote for GMail. I want to reformat and then forward every mail from a specific sender to a Mail2SMS provider.

When I receive the mail it will be tagged with an label - "Alarmanlage".

The formating works fine, but my script don't use the last mail from the sender the format and forward. I don't find the failure to get the last mail of a thread.

I hope someone can help!

```
function sendsms(){
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Alarmanlage");  
if(label == null){
GmailApp.createLabel('Alarmanlage');
}
else{
var threads = label.getThreads(0,1);  

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {  
  var count = threads[i].getMessageCount(); 

  var message = threads[i].getMessages()[count];

  var from = message.getFrom();
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  var date = message.getDate();

  var msg = message.getBody();
  msg = msg.replace("<div><br>","");
  var endofmsg = msg.indexOf("<br>");
  msg = msg.substring(0, endofmsg); 

  GmailApp.sendEmail("xxxh@mail2sms.com", msg)

  message.moveToTrash()

}
label.removeFromThreads(threads);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your var message use :

```
var thread = threads[i];
var messages = thread.getMessages();
var message= messages[thread.getMessageCount()-1];
```

Stéphane